# Creating recursive folders with a linux bash script

Tags: bash, algorithm, recursion, mkdir

I've asked this once before, and it was marked as it needs more details. Well here it is in great detail.

Goal is to have a script that creates folders as follows:

> main

- After creating a single folder called 'main' inside that folder it will create 6 'a' folders named with numbers and letters respectively "1a 2a 3a 4a 5a 6a"
- After creating those 6 'a' folders, it's going to create 6 'b' folders inside EACH of those 6 'a' folders. So each 'a' folder will contain "1b 2b 3b 4b 5b 6b"
- After creating those 6 'b' folders, it's going to create 6 'c' folders in each of those 6 'b' folders. So, they will all contain the folders "1c 2c 3c 4c 5c 6c"
- After that, it will create 6 'd' folders in each of 'c' folders. So the 'c' folders will contain "1d 2d 3d 4d 5d 6d"
- After that, it will create 6 'e' folders in each of 'd' folders. So the 'd' folders will contain "1e 2e 3e 4e 5e 6e"
- After that, it will create 6 'f' folders in each of 'e' folders. So the 'e' folders will contain "1f 2f 3f 4f 5f 6f"
- All 'f' folders will be empty

The end result should be:

1. One 'main' folder that has 6 'a' folders
2. All 'a' folders should have 6 'b' folders
3. All 'b' folders should have 6 'c' folders
4. All 'c' folders should have 6 'd' folders
5. All 'd' folders should have 6 'e' folders
6. All 'e' folders should have 6 'f' folders
7. All 'f' folders must remain empty

This should be a linux shell script of course.

I don't have the code to post, I've been trying with for loops where i is from 1 to 6 and it creates a folder named that.
If you really want the code I wrote for this problem I'll gladly paste the 50000+ lines of mkdir that I wrote months ago. This problem recently came to my mind and I wanted to see if anyone else could find a solution, because nothing I tried worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: My thoughts? Certainly possible. How about coming up with your thoughts and perhaps a draft script which shows where you are stuck? If you need help with your script, I guess there is somebody who can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
    for b in 1 2 3 4 5 6
    do
        for c in 1 2 3 4 5 6
        do
            for d in 1 2 3 4 5 6
            do
                for e in 1 2 3 4 5 6
                do
                    for f in 1 2 3 4 5 6
                    do
                        mkdir -p main/a$a/b$b/c$c/d$d/e$e/f$f
                    done
                done
            done
        done
    done
done
```

but I'm sure you can improve it...

Comment: or only `mkdir -p main/a{1..6}/b{1..6}/c{1..6}/d{1..6}/e{1..6}/f{1..6}`

Comment: Yes this did the trick! Looking at it now, I kinda feel dumb :/. Thank you so much for helping me. I clearly have to study a LOT more. And no, no improvements to your program will be needed. Thank you PinkFloyd.